# Windows Media Player - library format

Tags: file-format

Is anyone aware of any documentation (official or reverse-engineered) on the Windows Media Player library / database `.wmdb` format?  (Specifically WMP 12).

The file resides at `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player\CurrentDatabase_[nnn].wmdb`. It's a binary file, seemingly uncompressed.

I'm willing to work on this, but don't want to waste my time if it's already been done!

Research:

- Neither the [Mulimedia.cx](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Windows_Media_Player) wiki page, nor the [hachoir](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/hachoir-parser) utility seem to have any information about it.
- [This blog post](http://simplecarver.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/windows-media-player-database-currentdatabase_372-wmdb-files/) links to a product called [Simple Carver](http://www.simplecarver.com/tool.php?toolname=WMDB%20Extractor%20for%20CurrentDatabase_372), a paid forensics utility, that claims to support the format.
- [This forum post](http://zunerama.com/forum/index.php?topic=4487.15) indicates that WMP 11 came with a `wmdbexport.exe` utility, but this doesn't exist in WMP 12.

Specifically, there are a few tools/scripts I've wanted to write that would need to directly manipulate this database.

Comment: Although they don't have wmdb. I'd like to note that Wotsit.com has a lot of formats.

Comment: Hope you are doing well! I am doing a forensic research on Windows Media Player for my Master's Thesis and I am having the same issue, I cannot understand the structure of the "CurrentDatabase_xxx.wmdb" file. If you have figured out about the structure and documented it. Can you please share it with me? It would be a great to me. Thanks in advance.